# Twilio clientId is not valid when dequeing a call from a TwiML queue

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio's TaskRouter to redirect inbound calls to agents.

I'm using the `<enqueue>` verb to enqueue the inbound call and when a worker is assigned I return the following JSON to call the agent:

```
{
    "instruction": "dequeue",
    "to": "client:company-1-client",
    "from": "+101388558",
    "post_work_activity_sid": "<ActivitySID>",
}
```

I've added `allow_client_incoming("company-1-client")` but I get the following error:

```
code 21211

Called is not valid: client:company-1-client
```

I'm following this tutorial to get TaskRouter to call the my agent: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/twiml-integration

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So It turns out my setup was correct. The only problem was that one is not allowed to user "-" in the client name.

From Twilio Docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client

> The client identifier currently may only contain alpha-numeric and
>   underscore characters.